# Threading and Estimote Beacons ranging

Tags: android, multithreading, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, estimote

I'm having some difficulties understanding how the `onBeaconsDiscovered` works. Does the code inside this method is being performed on a separate thread? What if I want to do some networking stuff inside an AsyncTask to fetch some data related to Beacons discovered, is it better to open a new thread to each discovered beacon or to open a new thread to each list of beacons discovered by ranging, known that the same beacons might be discovered more than once in a short period of time?

Answer (score 0):

All the Estimote Android SDK callbacks are called on the message queue of the thread that instantiated the `BeaconManager`. Unless you're doing something really, really weird, this means the main/UI thread.